# Get selected date in jqueryui datepicker inline mode

Tags: jquery-ui, calendar

I am trying to use jqueryui datepicker. I want to use the inline mode.

I want to know how can I get the selected date when user selects a date. Where to get  and how to get ?

Answer (score 65):

You can retrieve the date by using the getDate function:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( 'getDate' );
```

The value is returned as a JavaScript Date object.

If you want to use this value when the user selects a date, you can use the onSelect event:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
   }
});
```

The first parameter is in this case the selected Date as String. Use [parseDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) to convert it to a JS Date Object.

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker for the full jQuery UI DatePicker reference.

Comment: This helped me to convert date to different format after `onSelect`. Example: `$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));`

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day.  var dateAsString = dateText; helped me to get the selected date.

Answer (score 19):

```
$(document).on("change", "#datepickerdiv", function () {
         alert($(this).val())


    })
```

This is the simplest answer in Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to work with close `event` but it also used to trigger when calendar is open and I click somewhere else on the scree. Eventually calendar loses `focus` and `close event` it called. So i found this one;

```
  onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            function isDonePressed() {
                return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
            }
            if (isDonePressed()) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        }
```